# Как защититься от SQL INJ

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, сегодня я с таким вопросом - как лучше всего защититься от SQL inj, собственными руками.
В гуглах ничего внятного на этот вопрос не нашел, кроме богов маркетинга, предлагающих свои крутые скрипты за не хилые суммы, которые "помогут защититься от всего, даже от геморроя".
Вот кто то говорит, что достаточно набора из strip_tags, htmlspecialchars и mysql_escape_string, а кто то утверждает, что это всего лишь детский сад. 
Так вот, хотелось бы знать Ваше мнение и практическое использование всего этого дела.

Comment: > strip_tags, htmlspecialchars

имеют нулевое отношение к инъекциям

> Так вот, хотелось бы знать Ваше мнение и практическое использование всего этого дела.

по факту нужно всего лишь одно - гарантия того, что попавшая на вход строка так и останется строкой внутри выполняемой команды. Это можно выполнить простой функцией на коленке, можно использовать PDO и prepared statements, которые хороши тем, что разделяют команду и параметры, поэтому поломать команду через конкатенацию тупо невозможно.

Comment: >В гуглах ничего внятного на этот вопрос не нашел

Это как нужно постараться, чтобы не найти? 

Ну, для начала можно перевести взгляд чуть правей и ниже своего вопроса :)

![alt text][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/XXZDlsx.png

Comment: @Etki а что же это? без библиотек типо уже никуда? Кругом одни скрипткиддди? 
Хотелось бы это всё своими ручками проворачивать.

Comment: @Виталий RS, когда вы используете любую функцию PHP, вы не библиотеку *типо* используете?

При чем тут скрипткидди - не очень понял.

Comment: @Виталий RS, "киддизм" - это как раз писать своими ручками велосипеды. Которые на деле оказываются с квадратными колёсами, ржавой рамой и рвущейся каждые 20 метров цепью.

Comment: @Виталий RS, тогда почему вы вообще используете PHP? Только CGI, только хардкор! А вообще, в программировании есть замечательный принцип: Not Invented Here. В вольном переводе на русский это звучит как "не изобретай велосипед". У вас значительно больше шанс пропустить что-нибудь, пиша свой костыль для предотвращения инъекций, чем у команды, которая профессионально и на протяжении большого времени разрабатывает библиотеку.

Comment: @fori1ton да в общем то я и сам и PDO использую, и тд. 
Мне больше интересны сами механизмы.

Comment: используйте в PHP класс PDO, а все необходимые условия передавайте через параметры. 
SQL-иньекции отсекаются данным классом при разборе параметров и не выполняются.

Comment: Используйте mysql_real_escape_string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

Оборачивать данные в запросе в

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

Но я не вижу смысла, так как MySQL уже Deprecated, Начиная с версии php 5.5

Поэтому лучше использовать MySQLi или PDO:MySQL
с их prepared методами.

Всё гениальное просто :)

Answer (score 0):

Предложу почитать "24 смертных греха компьютерной безопасности", там есть отдельная глава об SQL-Injection и рассмотрены типичные **ошибки** и методы защиты. И достаточно хорошо написано, imho.

Answer (score -1):

Советую ознакомиться с OWASP Top 10. Вам интереснее всего будет [именно это](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Там написана кромешная ерунда, "Escaping User Supplied Input"